# Constraint animation not working on device but on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, autolayout, uiviewanimation

Im using a UIView animations to move up/down a view (Using Autolayout) .
 Animation works on simulator but it doesn't on actual device. What could be the problem? Code to do the animation is here

```
[self layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
            self.animationConstraint.constant = -190;
            [self bringSubviewToFront:self.containerView];
            [self.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
```

I have checked the memory usage, but it doesn't cross more than 2% at the time of doing the animations.

Comment: Wouldn't [self layoutIfNeeded]; already update the UI element to the new position without animation and hence why you don't see anything on the device? What happens if you comment out that line ?

Comment: Well, the animation is not happening. But the position changes, like it just jumps to the position.

Comment: I believe the way it works is you put the constraint.constant update outside the UIView animation block and put the layoutIfNeeded inside the animation block.

Comment: Solved. I had to re-layout the parent view, not the view the constraint was attached to. So instead of [self.containerView layoutIfNeeded]; , [selflayoutIfNeeded]; did the trick. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Is the simulator device the same like the actual device in regard to `iOS and display size`?